# Java URLConnection Error

Tags: java

This error is from a PC connected to a comcast modem. Is port blocking an issue when a person is trying to make an outbound TCP channel with a Java URL . . .  the relevant code is :

```
URL u = new URL("mailto:someguy@gmail.com");    // make a mailto: url
URLConnection c = u.openConnection();   // make its urlconnection
c.connect();                // connect to mail host

catch (Exception e) {   // handle any exceptions, print error message
  System.err.println(e);
}
```

The console returns the message :

connect. Timeout = -1
java.net.UnknownHostException: mailhost

Comment: Do you want to connect to a mail server?

Comment: -1 for not doing your research: `mailto:mail@address.to` is not a valid URI per se, it's a mere indication on what to do with that address (in that case, open a client e-mail-application).

Comment: @Bobby check http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/net/www/protocol/mailto/MailToURLConnection.java.html. I was surprised.

Comment: This is not how you send email. Are you trying to open the default mail client on a computer? Are you trying to connect to the smtp server of gmail?

Comment: @HemalPandya: Wow, cool. Didn't know that...though, I'm unable to pinpoint if the URL-Class is on its own able to create the MailToUrlConnection-Class by calling `openConnection`.

Comment: MailToURLConnection is part of OpenJDK 7 and not Java 7. I can't find it in the Java 7 api. Perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: @Ali I am using Java 6 and I still get the same `MailToUrlConnection`. The error would have been different if the class did not exist.

Comment: I fixed the application, I wasn't specifying the smtp server of my ISP. To whoever docked me, you're incorrect, http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt and search for mailto. To everyone else, thank you very much, 

Joel

Comment: @Literati where did you find **Java** documentation for its use? Where are you specifying the smtp server?

Comment: @Hermal `MailToURLConnection` is NOT in Java 6 or 7 or any earlier version. It is part of the [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) implementation of J2SE specifications. [Download and install OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/install/) and use that as your Java JDK and the problem will probably go away. I have checked, OpenJDK 6 has `MailToURLConnection` class.

Comment: @LiteratiInsolitus according to [java 6 api for `URL`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) the following are the only guaranteed protocol handlers `http, https, ftp, file, and jar` what platform are you on? if it's Linux or OSX chances are that you are running OpenJDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception `java.net.UnknownHostException: mailhost` is thrown to indicate that the IP address of a host could not be determined.

I reckon you might be trying to [send a mail](http://www.javacommerce.com/displaypage.jsp?name=javamail.sql&id=18274).

Answer (score 1):

`MailToURLConnection` is NOT in Java 6 or 7 or any earlier version. It is part of the [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) implementation of J2SE specifications. [Download and install](http://openjdk.java.net/install/) OpenJDK and use that as your Java JDK and the problem will probably go away. I have checked, [OpenJDK 6](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk6/) has the [`MailToURLConnection`](http://srcrr.org/java/oracle/openjdk/6/reference/sun/net/www/protocol/mailto/MailToURLConnection.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find any documentation but it seems `URL.openConnection()` above creates a `sun.net.www.protocol.mailto.MailToURLConnection`. Looking at the code [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/net/www/protocol/mailto/MailToURLConnection.java.html) it creates an [SmtpClient](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/net/smtp/SmtpClient.html).

This creates a connection to `System.getProperty("mail.host")` or to `"localhost"` or to `"mailhost"`. I guess the `"mail.host"` is not defined for you and localhost is not accepting the connection so the dns error for mailhost.

Where did find information to use "mailto:" anyway? That same place should also have the rest of usage documentation. If you were just trying something or ran into it accidentally then I would advice not to use it.